# How do I use Camel 2.15 with the pom.xml generated by Fabric8 Maven archetype

Tags: apache-camel, spring-boot, fabric8

I'm excited about the release of Camel 2.15. I want to use it with Fabric8. How do I modify the pom.xml generated by the Fabric8 Spring Boot archetype so it uses Camel 2.15?

http://fabric8.io/gitbook/springBootContainer.html

It seems to default to 2.13.2

Comment: Which version of fabric8 are you talking about?

Comment: The version that gets installed when following these instructions: http://fabric8.io/v2/openShiftDocker.html

Comment: You can just change the version in the pom.xml. Though latest release of fabric8 2.0.32 should have been upgraded to Camel 2.15.0 - and all its archetypes are generated based on all the quickstarts - https://github.com/fabric8io/quickstarts/tree/master/archetypes - so they should use the same versions as the quickstarts.

Comment: The confusion seems to be around:
 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=springboot-camel-archetype

versus 

    -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-camel-archetype

They both work. The documentation uses springboot-camel-archetype

Comment: It seems I need a DOCKER_REGISTRY environment variable setup to run the spring-boot-camel-archetype

Comment: The springboot-camel-archetype uses springboot-camel-archetype:1.2.0.Beta4

Comment: The documentation here is wrong: http://fabric8.io/gitbook/springBootContainer.html - it references the wrong archetype - spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay so you are using Fabric8 v1. That is no longer maintained in the community, as we moved on to Fabric8 v2 - which is docker and kubernetes based.

For Fabric8 v1 - only the parts related to OSGi / Karaf is supported as part of the JBoss Fuse product. They are working on a new JBoss Fuse 6.2 release that will contained Fabric8 v1. But that version does not support docker / spring-boot etc - only the Karaf/OSGi parts.

I suggest to move on and try Fabric8 v2. For that you would either need a kubernetes platform such as OpenShift3, Google Cloud, or an alternative is to use the Java based implementation which is known as Jube.

The new documentation is here, notice the v2 in the link: http://fabric8.io/v2/index.html

Comment: I was using the link that Google gave me when I searched for Fabric8 and Spring Boot. This explains things - thanks.

Comment: Yeah maybe we should remove the old v1 docs, as that over time belongs in the JBoss Fuse product

Comment: I still can't get the project created with the archetype to build: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact io.fabric8:fabric8-project:pom:${fabric8.version} from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 64: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/fabric8/fabric8-project/${fabric8.version}/fabric8-project-${fabric8.version}.pom @ line 46, column 19 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Ah yeah some of those dont work - I have logged a ticket: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/3591

Comment: Instead just try the quickstarts, eg clone it from github and follow the instructions - the spring-boot quickstarts should work then -> http://fabric8.io/v2/example.html